# Auction when player has not enough money to buy?

Tags: power-grid

A player puts a power plant up for auction.
Is that allowed if he doesn't have enough money to buy it himself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No he is not.

According to the [rules (Pdf)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwjB5M3HrrHjAhVM_qQKHY5tBEQQFjACegQIARAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Friograndegames.com%2FgetFile.php%3Fid%3D698&usg=AOvVaw1tzr-W7n_-KFb3Hy3-c7Ay):

> The player chooses one power plant from the actual market (top row) and then makes a bid to purchase it (**the player must bid at least the minimum bid** (number of the
>   power plant), but may start with a higher bid.

The player starting the auction must start with the opening bid.

If he wins the bid he must pay the bank:

> He pays his highest bid to the bank and takes the power plant.

This implies that one must have enough money for the bid.

Comment: Correct. I can't believe I missed that...